# How to interrupt an audio recording with the twilio php api

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm using the twilio php api and I can't seem to find any way to interrupt the audio files from playing immediately a gather key is pressed.

This is what I have currently

```
$voiceResponse->gather(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => $storeResponseURL, 'finishOnKey' => '#']);
$voiceResponse->redirect($noResponseURL, ['method' => 'POST']);
```

Please, I need help on this.

Comment: Can you show the TwiML that plays the audio file?  I suspect its outside of the `<Gather>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In your [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) from your example you have the [`finishOnKey` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-finish) set to "#". So the `<Gather>` will only finish when your caller presses "#" not any other key.

Your `<Gather>` doesn't appear to contain any other [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) either. If you want to be able to interrupt audio then you need to [nest a `<Say>` or `<Play>` element inside the `<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#nesting-rules).

If you want to complete the input after just one character, then your best bet is to actually use the [`numDigits` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-digits) and set it to `1`.

Putting that all together, your TwiML generation should look like this:

```
$voiceResponse = new Twiml();
$gather = $voiceResponse->gather(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => $storeResponseURL, 'numDigits' => '1']);
$gather->play('/gather_audio.mp3');
$voiceResponse->redirect($noResponseURL, ['method' => 'POST']);
```

Let me know if that helps!